# How to pattern match on SomeException?

Tags: haskell, exception, pattern-matching

Consider the following code:

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

handler :: SomeException -> IO ()
handler (SomeException e) = do
  case e of
    -- COMMENTED OUT DivideByZero -> putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
    _ -> putStrLn $ "handler: exception is: " ++ (show e) ++ " of type: " ++ (show $ typeOf e)

blowUp = do
    putStrLn (show (1 `div` 0))

main = catch blowUp handler
```

It works just fine and prints out:

```
handler: exception is: divide by zero of type: ArithException
```

However if I uncomment the `DivideByZero` line, I get the following compile-time error:

```
testexc2.hs:7:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘e’
                  with actual type ‘ArithException’
      ‘e’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          SomeException :: forall e. Exception e => e -> SomeException,
        in an equation for ‘handler’
        at testexc2.hs:5:10-24
    • In the pattern: DivideByZero
      In a case alternative:
          DivideByZero -> putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case e of
          DivideByZero -> putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
          _ -> putStrLn
                 $ "handler: exception is: "
                     ++ (show e) ++ " of type: " ++ (show $ typeOf e)
    • Relevant bindings include e :: e (bound at testexc2.hs:5:24)
  |
7 |     DivideByZero -> putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
  |
```

Is there a way to pattern match on `SomeException`'s wrapped exception (other than the wildcard `_` pattern)?

If yes: how?

If not: why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe e
```

as in (untested)

```
handler :: SomeException -> IO ()
handler e@(SomeException e') = case fromException e of
   Just DivideByZero ->
      putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
   Nothing ->
      putStrLn $ "handler: exception is: " ++ (show e') ++ " of type: " ++ (show $ typeOf e')
```

or even

```
handler :: SomeException -> IO ()
handler e@(SomeException e')
   | Just DivideByZero <- fromException e 
      = putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
   | Just _ <- fromException e :: Maybe IOException
      = putStrLn $ "handler: IOException!"
   ...
   | otherwise 
      = putStrLn $ "handler: exception is: " ++ (show e') ++ " of type: " ++ (show $ typeOf e')
```

It is also possible to play with `Typeable` directly, e.g. using `cast` or (maybe) `eqT` to test if the exception is of a given type.

Even with current GHC, I believe `PatternSynonyms` could be exploited to allow a syntax similar to yours:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms, TypeApplications  #-}

import Control.Exception

-- ArithException, only DivideByZero subcase
pattern ExDivisionByZero <- (fromException -> Just DivideByZero)

-- IOException, all subcases
pattern ExIOException    <- (fromException -> Just (_ :: IOException))

handler :: SomeException -> IO ()
handler ExDivisionByZero = putStrLn $ "handler: DivideByZero!"
handler ExIOException    = putStrLn $ "handler: IOException!"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of `fromException`, but my question is: why can't you pattern match on `SomeException` directly?

Comment: @stf Because it can have an unknown amount of forms. There is no exhaustive list of exception types: any module can add its own exception type by defining a proper `instance Exception T` for any user-defined `T`. In principle, this could be allowed, but it would require some more magic from the compiler. By default, all type information is erased and is no longer available at runtime; the fact that the `Exception` class overrides this and keeps runtime type information is ... exceptional indeed. In general, there is no way to test "is this unknown value of this type?" at runtime.

Comment: @stf the last alternative above is the nicest one, IMO, but it does require one to define a bunch of custom patterns.